# Use VBA to convert letter case

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing VBA macro that will convert the string in proper case but with some restriction.

### Beginning text:

1. DTest dk;G3Gj
2. _dsc0148A
3. 1pottery2
4. Articiart147
5. If you don't NEed It
6. Pressed_pleasure
7. On_The-Floor

### Desired result:

1. Dtest Dk;G3gj
2. _Dsc0148a
3. 1Pottery2
4. Articiart147
5. If You Don't Need It
6. Pressed_Pleasure
7. On_The-Floor

### Attempt 1:

```
Sub ChangePCase()
 rownum = 2
 colnum = 1

 ActiveSheet.Range("a2", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Select

     For Each Cell In Selection
       mystr = Cells(rownum, colnum).value

        Text = WorksheetFunction.Proper(mystr)
        Cells(rownum, colnum + 1) = Text
        rownum = rownum + 1
     Next
End Sub
```

**Result**

1. Dtest Dk;G3Gj
2. _Dsc0148A
3. 1Pottery2
4. Articiart147
5. If You Don'T Neeed It
6. Pressed_Pleasure
7. On_The-Floor

some characters gets capital after digit or special character.

How I can restrict the characters after special character not to be capital, but if first character of a word is special character then the second character should be capital as the 2nd number.

### Attempt 2:

My other code Gives some better results but it don't capitalize the second character of a word after special character. Code with output is

```
Sub Propername()
rownum = 2
colnum = 1

ActiveSheet.Range("a2", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Select

For Each Cell In Selection

 Text = Trim(StrConv(Cells(rownum, colnum).value, vbProperCase))
 Cells(rownum, colnum + 1) = Text
rownum = rownum + 1
Next
 End Sub
```

**Result**

1. Dtest Dk;k3kj
2. _dsc0148a
3. 1pottery2
4. Articiart147
5. If You Don't Neeed It
6. Pressed_pleasure
7. On_the#fl#oor

in second and third 2nd character is not capital while in 6 p of pleasure is also not capital.

Comment: It is unclear what rules should be applied to suit all these outcomes - do you have a rule summary?

Comment: `How I can restrict the characters after special character not to be capital, but if first character of a word is special character then the second character should be capital` - I'm afraid that is impossible. As brettdj pointed out, you should set up your rules clearly first for yourself. The coding is then almost done already.

Comment: You need to list out each unique rule and check if that cell meets a criteria.

Comment: nothing special here. Standard Rules apply, only one restriction is that if a word starts with some special character then the next alphabet should be capital.

Comment: You have non-standard rules about what constitutes a word. Generally this is any string separated by space characters or other normal punctuation. It seems like you are also assuming that some (#, _, etc.) but not all special characters are word delimiters.  Because you have not explicitly defined your rules & logic, it is going to be very difficult for anyone to help you.  The solution is what @TKEyi60 suggests: Establish the rules in your code, and then test each cell or substring.  It is going to be tricky, because your rules seem tricky.

Comment: there is not need to apply rules to each cell. Its simply can be done by identifying the word by delimiter (all special characters including white spaces such as _. #, ; 1,2, etc) used and then capitalizing the first character.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand what your rules are for this either, but I feel that Regular Expressions may help your code identify the patterns you're trying to find.  :-)

Comment: @itfeature.com so why does `1dk;G3Gj` become `1Dk;G3gj` with `g` after `3` now lower case?

Comment: @brettdj: 1dk; G3Gj should be 1Dk; G3gj as after space second word's first letter is character not number. after 3 g is not word it is part of word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [array](/questions/tagged/array)/[regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) meets your requirements

*Updated: I have added fix to address the limitations of the [Proper case function and apostrophes](http://www.consil.co.uk/blog/2012/11/20/problems-with-excel-proper-case-function-and-apostrophes/)*

```
Sub NotScared_butConfused()
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Dim X
Dim lngCnt As Long

X = Range([a2], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "([\_\-\$;:\s])+([a-z])"
.Global = True
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
X(lngCnt, 1) = Application.Proper(LCase$(X(lngCnt, 1)))
If .test(X(lngCnt, 1)) Then
Set objRegMC = .Execute(X(lngCnt, 1))
For Each regm In objRegMC
Mid$(X(lngCnt, 1), regm.firstindex + 2, 1) = UCase$(regm.submatches(1))
Next
End If
With Application
X(lngCnt, 1) = .Substitute(.Proper(.Substitute(X(lngCnt, 1), "'", "zyx")), "zyx", "'")
End With
Next
End With
If lngCnt > 1 Then [b2].Resize(UBound(X), 1) = X
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for code, It has problem with this string "if you don't need it". It gives output as "If You Don'T Need It". according to standard rules after apostrophe letter should be small.

Comment: hahaha, not scared but confused. Perhaps all is because of exampled used. Simple requirement is that if a word starts with number or any specially character then next letter should be capital (#star). if there is any special character being used as word separator then next letter to this delimiter should be capital (public_proceed). And regarding language rule letter after apostrophe should not be capital (dont't).

Comment: Wow, the Excel `Proper` function  [adds capitals after an apostrope](http://www.consil.co.uk/blog/2012/11/20/problems-with-excel-proper-case-function-and-apostrophes/). I will update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hope all have understand the rules not mine but standard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the people are afraid or unable to understand the problem.

There is programming problem in proper command of excel as it don't properly change the case of string for example write this command in excel's cell

```
=proper("If you don't Need It")
```

you will see the results without quotes

```
"If You Don'T Need It"
```

for this output people never ever afraid.

I have programmed the following code.

```
Sub Propername()
rownum = 2
colnum = 1

ActiveSheet.Range("a2", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Select

For Each Cell In Selection
   FullName = Cells(rownum, colnum).value
'capitalize the first letter after _. 
   For i = 1 To Len(FullName)
     pos = InStr(1, FullName, "_", vbTextCompare)

    If pos > 1 Then
     text1 = Trim(StrConv(Mid(FullName, 1, pos), vbProperCase))
     text2 = Trim(StrConv(Mid(FullName, pos + 1, 999), vbProperCase))
     Cells(rownum, colnum + 1) = text1 & text2
     cont = 1
    If InStr(1, text2, "_") Then
     pos1 = InStr(1, text2, "_")
     text3 = Trim(StrConv(Mid(text2, 1, pos1), vbProperCase))
     text4 = Trim(StrConv(Mid(text2, pos1 + 1, 999), vbProperCase))
     Cells(rownum, colnum + 1) = text1 & text3 & text4
    End If
   End If
 If pos = 0 Or InStr(1, text2, "_") = False Then cont = 0: Exit For Next
 'capitalize the second letter as capital if first letter is a digit or some special character in string
 Select Case Left(Cells(rownum, colnum).value, 1)
   Case "_", "#", "$", "-", "'", ";", ":"
      Text0 = Mid(FullName, 1, 1)
      text1 = StrConv(Mid(FullName, 2, 1), vbProperCase)
      text2 = Trim(StrConv(Mid(FullName, 3, 999), vbLowerCase))
      Cells(rownum, colnum + 1) = Text0 & text1 & text2
   Case 0 To 9
      Text0 = Mid(FullName, 1, 1)
      text1 = StrConv(Mid(FullName, 2, 1), vbProperCase)
      text2 = Trim(StrConv(Mid(FullName, 3, 999), vbLowerCase))
      Cells(rownum, colnum + 1) = Text0 & text1 & text2

 Case Else
    If cont <> 0 Then
     Text = Trim(StrConv(FullName, vbProperCase))
     Cells(rownum, colnum + 1) = Text
   End If
 End Select

rownum = rownum + 1
Next
 End Sub
```

I can be improved, especially if one can detect the location of special character in string.

Comment: If there are no special rules and you are looking for all non alphabetical characters, then why not run an if statement one time on each cell.  If the character is alphabetical, skip, else capitalize.  You can take each character and put it in a string variable that resets after each cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function mySC(txt, how) As String 'ST = string convert
'vbUpperCase   1   Converts the string to all uppercase.
'vbLowerCase   2   Converts the string to all lowercase.
'vbProperCase  3   Converts the first letter to every word to uppercase. All other characters are left as lowercase.
'vbUnicode     64  Converts the string to Unicode.
'vbFromUnicode 128 Converts the string from Unicode to the default code page of the system.
'
    mySC = StrConv(txt, how)
End Function
```